# Why does my laptop crash when I plug in an HDMI cable from my TV?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, video, hdmi

This has happened twice now. I don't know if it has any connection with my other ongoing problem detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/969700/why-does-my-laptop-fail-to-update-and-take-an-hour-to-restart), but when I play a streaming video and then plug a HDMI cable from my TV to my laptop, the laptop *sometimes* (not always) immediately crashes, and then goes through that whole updating/failing-to-update/restarting cycle described in my earlier post.

My wife's theory is that connecting the two devices *after* starting the streaming video on the laptop is the problem, and that I should first plug the cable into the new devices, and only *thereafter* start the video.

That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I am no expert on the subject - anybody?

Comment: It *is* an HDMI cable, after all. So is the sequence of when the HDMI cable is plugged in from the TV to the laptop relative to when the streaming video is started on the laptop important?

Comment: What happens if you before you open whatever you are streaming with (Netflix/VLC....), you connect your HDMI cable to the TV.  Now you have your desktop on the TV, then start streaming.  What happens?

Comment: I'm streaming content from a private site; I've downloaded the next "episode" (program segment) to an .mpf file, so if it crashes again tonight, it's apparently not really a *streaming* issue per se, but a cable or interface or ... some other... problem. At any rate, I am going to first make the connection between the two devices tonight, and THEN start the .mpf video.

Comment: Does it require a flash player in a browser? I have had flash crash when trying to play video without any speakers/headphones attached (i.e. no possible audio output). Plugging HDMI also implicitly attaches/enables a new audio out.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any Flash involved; it runs in the default Windows media-playing app (WIndows 7/8). I consider Flash to be a virus; too bad it wasn't a flash in the pan.

Comment: Sounds like a screen resolution problem. Laptop is sending signals for a certain resolution while streaming app is sending another to compensate for the movie/show as a secondary screen. What happens is you connect laptop prior to streaming. Also what streaming app are you using?

Comment: It worked fine last night with a downloaded .mp4. I'm not sure (I don't know) what you mean by "streaming app" - I simply click on the icon for streaming on the site.